# I want to re-order the default fields on registration form

Tags: users

I want to change the order of the default fields on the user registration form like E-mail adress, password ect ...

[image: The fields]

I have no idea how to order these. (I'm a noob at Drupal by the way)

Comment: A Drupal user cannot exist without these values, so they are always shown. Why do you intend to hide them?

Comment: These fields are required. You cannot just delete them.

Comment: I want to custom them, place these fields in the order I want

Comment: Then you should have asked for that ;). Gimme a sec to write an anwer.

Comment: Do you want to only change order?

Comment: Yes I want to change them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to write a custom module for this, there is some good reading here. https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7.

You should create a folder like `/sites/modules/<module_name>`.

Create a `<module_name>.info` file

```
name = Custom order of fields
description = Customizes field orders
core = 7.x
```

Also create a `<module_name>.module` file an add the following code. The weights control the order, lower is higher on the page.

Please note that this might cause some problems with the field ordering if you add or change fields with the manage fields UI, so you might have to tweak the values a bit later on. You can go the the manage fields page and in the right top click `Show row weights`, this allows you to change the weights of the fields created with the UI.

```
function <module_name>_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Move the whole group.
  $form['account']['#weight'] = -10;

  // Move a single property within the group.
  $form['account']['name']['#weight'] = -10;
  $form['account']['mail']['#weight'] = 5;
  $form['account']['pass']['#weight'] = 15;

  // Move a value out of the group and order it.
  $form['name'] = $form['account']['name'];
  unset($form['account']['name']);
  $form['name']['#weight'] = -10;
}
```

Finally if you want the order to persist on the account edit page, copy all code again into a function named    `<module_name>_form_user_account_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)`

Comment: So you put this code into the .module file. I did it but I have a basic error with the double arrow "=>"

Comment: Apologies, should have been a regular `=`.

Comment: You are welcome. You can hit the tick symbol left of the question to mark it as solved.

Comment: I have another question, I created a new custom field into that registration form, how can I change its height ? I guess it's not : $form['account']['field_new']

Comment: Go to the field configuration page where you added the field. Hit show row weights in right top and set it manually.

Comment: thats great but i have to change the order of inputs inside the address widget, and the weighting in the hook is only for the widget (includes ever input). how can i change the order for inputs inside a widget (address in my case) ?